# What is the maximum length of a named Semaphore's name?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, semaphore

What is the maximum length of a [Semaphore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore.aspx)'s name?  It makes sense that there would be one, as it maps to an underlying kernel semaphore, but the documentation does not seem to specify it precisely.

Comment: Probably because the MSDN has stated [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54wk4yfd(v=vs.80).aspx) since .NET 2.0 that the maximum length is 260. Granted that's not a very good reason for a downvote.

Answer (score 3):

The maximum length of a Semaphore's name is 260 characters.  Exceeding this limit will result in a [ArgumentException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentexception.aspx) with the message of:

`The name can be no more than 260 characters in length.`